# Facebook Graph API, PHP SDK: How to echo out User posts?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Facebook SDK PHP edition. I've been using this resource to get everything I have done completed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted

```
<?php
    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'MYID',
        'app_secret' => 'MYSECRET',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    try {
        $response = $fb->get('/me');
        $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
    }
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    echo 'Logged in as ' . $userNode->getName();
?>
```

As far as this goes, everything works and spits out "Logged in as MY NAME"

What if I were to want to echo out all the post information for a particular ID. Say for example, https://www.facebook.com/EuropeanCommission

and I wanted to change my code on the 10th line to be:

```
$response = $fb->get('/EuropeanCommission/posts');
```

What else would I have to put and what would the echo statement be to echo out all the posts for this "page"? Is my get statement even correct to use in line with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=EuropeanCommission%2Fposts&version=v2.6

Comment: Note (according to my limited understanding) that you cannot use a personal FB ID name as part of the GET. You can only use FB page names. 

You can use the FB ID number in the GET, but first the FB user needs to create a FB app on the user's personal page, and get them to give you the APP_ID and APP_SECRET values. 

Once you have that information, your code should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use print_r or var_dump to echo the data you want to.

in your case:

var_dump($userNode);

or

print_r($userNode);

This will print an array but if you want to print it in json.

echo json_encode($userNode);